# Does Intel centrino advanced-n wifi 6205 support packet injection? (For penetration testing)

Tags: security

Like it says does intel centrino advanced-n wifi 6205 support packet injection? I am a pen tester its not for unauthorized hacking....

Comment: Does Monitor mode and packet injection work with virtual box ? And which kali Linux version supposed Intel Centrino Advance-N 6205 for aircrack-ng ? Share it pls

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Centrino advanced-n 6205 supports injection. Tested on my own machine.
Make sure that you kill the Network-Manager process before attempting injection.

Comment: Links with additional information: https://forums.kali.org/showthread.php?19248-Wifi-packet-injection-fails-on-Intel-6205-wifi-card http://www.phoronix.com/forums/showthread.php?71479-Intel-Centrino-Advanced-N-6205-AGN

Comment: @pelo Monitor mode and packet injection work with virtual box ? And which kali Linux version supposed Intel Centrino Advance-N 6205 for aircrack-ng ?

Answer (score 0):

From [aircrack-ng](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=compatibility_drivers#which_is_the_best_card_to_buy) page:

> Intel wireless cards are common devices found inside most laptops
>   apart from Broadcom, Atheros, Ralink and Realtek. These devices has
>   native linux support and generally do work well for most parts except
>   for Intel's older chipsets such as ipw2200. 3945 owners are
>   recommended to use iwl3945 as the older driver ipw3945 does not have
>   monitor or injection capability and requires ipwraw-ng and is often
>   not easy to work with ipwraw-ng. Owners of 4965 and later has support
>   with iwlagn.

Also if you plan to buy one of those then read this : [What is the best wireless card to buy](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=faq#what_is_the_best_wireless_card_to_buy)